# Accordion: How to Keep current tab expanded when expanding another?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

i have an accordion like this:

```
<div class="div_accordion">
    <accordion class="my_accordion">
        <accordion-group is-open="value1.open">
          <accordion-heading>Heading 1</accordion-heading>
          <p> Para 1</p>
        </accordion-group>

        <accordion-group is-open="value2.open">
          <accordion-heading>Heading 2</accordion-heading>
          <p> Para 2</p>
        </accordion-group>

        <accordion-group is-open="value3.open">
          <accordion-heading>Heading 3</accordion-heading>
          <p> Para 3</p>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

when opening another it closes currently opened tab.

I want to keep current tab opened when opening other.

using accordion how can i do this in angular/jquery?

Comment: Which accordion directive you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
<div class="div_accordion">
    <accordion class="my_accordion" close-others="false">
        <accordion-group is-open="value1.open">
          <accordion-heading>Heading 1</accordion-heading>
          <p> Para 1</p>
        </accordion-group>

        <accordion-group is-open="value2.open">
          <accordion-heading>Heading 2</accordion-heading>
          <p> Para 2</p>
        </accordion-group>

        <accordion-group is-open="value3.open">
          <accordion-heading>Heading 3</accordion-heading>
          <p> Para 3</p>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```